# How to move large number of folders in the same place with R

Tags: r

I apologize for such a basic question but I couldnt find the answer anywhere. Let's say I have directory A, which has subdirectories B and C and each of them have a folder D. Now, how would I move all the D folders in the same place, say directory E ? I'm working with thousands of subdirectories by the way, hence the need of automation.

Thank you

Comment: You can look at the docs for `file.copy`

Comment: use [glob](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/Sys.glob)